# Spring Security authenticationManager does not work

Tags: spring, testing

when i want to use classe AuthenticationFilter the spring security dont found methode authenticationManager
0

In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 we deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration.

To assist with the transition to this new style of configuration, we have compiled a list of common use-cases and the suggested alternatives going forward In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 we deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration.

To assist with the transition to this new style of configuration, we have compiled a list of common use-cases and the suggested alternatives going forward know for spring laste version

Classe AuthenticationFilter

`public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{

```
private final   AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;



public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}


@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException{
    
    try {
        
        UserLoginRequest creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), UserLoginRequest.class);
        
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getEmail(),creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
        //return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getEmail(),creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}


@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException{
    
    String userName = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername(); 
    
    String token = Jwts.builder()
                        .setSubject(userName)
                        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_SECRET )
                        .compact();
    
    UserService userService = (UserService)SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
    
    UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(userName);
    
    res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    res.addHeader("user_id", userDto.getUserId());
}`
```

classe config
`@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity {

```
private final UserService userDetailsService;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
private AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

public WebSecurity(UserService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    super();
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}




@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
     http
            
            .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
            .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
            //.addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
            .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));//methode authenticationManager|()not found here
            
    return http.build();
}




protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}`
```